# Conditionally apply Android notification builder methods

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When using a NotificationCompat builder in Android, how can I conditionally apply one of the methods?

```
return new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle(notificationBuilder)
    .setBigContentTitle(bigContentTitle)
    .bigPicture(imageBitmap)
    .setSummaryText(summaryText)// only apply if parameter length > 0
    .build();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of an builder, it will build the object for you when you call methods on it.

When using a builder you can chain all methods to build your object or do it step by step (or an combination!)

```
NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle builder = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle(notificationBuilder);
```

Which you can use like every other object.

```
builder.setBigContentTitle(bigContentTitle)
       .bigPicture(imageBitmap);

if (summaryText.length() > 0){
    builder.setSummaryText(summaryText); // only apply if parameter length > 0
}

return (builder.build());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an `if` statement:

```
NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle thingy=new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle(notificationBuilder)
    .setBigContentTitle(bigContentTitle)
    .bigPicture(imageBitmap);

if (parameter.length()>0) {
  thingy.setSummaryText(summaryText);
}

return(thingy.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

.setSummary() can accept null as a parameter and is the same as if the method was never applied.